# Is there any way to force Safari to use a different UserAgent on a per site basis?

Tags: video, flash, safari, html5

Background: I use Safari 5.1.3 on Lion 10.7.3 on my 13" MacBook Air. I don't have Flash installed and have no intention of installing it. I frequently visit the [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/) site, which has a lot of video content. Unfortunately, if the BBC site detects you're using Safari on a Mac, it gives you the standard "You don't have the correct version of Flash installed" error message. If they only had the video available in Flash format that would be fine. However, they have pretty much all their video available in HTML5 format as well for users with iOS devices. If I switch my User Agent to "Safari - iPad" (using the Develop menu in Safari) the videos now load correctly as HTML5 videos.

What would be ideal is to be able to automatically have Safari switch the user agent for whenever I used the BBC News site. Is this possible?

Of course the real solution would be for the BBC to send HTML5 video for any device that doesn't have Flash installed, but that's beyond my control.

Comment: Once I learn how to write Safari extensions, I will answer your question 2.5 years late. I need this to trick Google into thinking that I have an old computer so it won't load unnecessary stuff.